# How to set scrollTop properly when scrolling with keys in div to keep selected item at same position

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, scroll

I'm trying to create my own input+dropdown control from scratch (in vue.js, though not relevant). I want to use mouse or keyboard for scrolling down the list of items.

For that I'm using a div with a fixed height and overflow-y and in that div, for each item, I use another div. When scrolling with the keyboard, I keep track of the selected item and use that to set the scrollTop position of the div, so that the scroll bar moves with the keyboard input and the selected item stays visible in the middle of the div. Here is the sample in fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/ce6k2a3j/11/

But the part I'm having issues with is setting the `.scrollTop` property when there are a lot of items in the list and there is some kind of scaling.

```
  setScrollPosition () {
    if(+this.keyIndex >= 6){
      this.$refs.testMainDiv.scrollTop = (+this.keyIndex - 6) * +this.$refs.testItemDiv[+this.keyIndex].clientHeight;
    }
    else{
      this.$refs.testMainDiv.scrollTop = 0;
    }
  },
```

My problem is that, in Windows 10, if I change the scaling of my display to 125% (since I use a 4k monitor), scrolling all the way down the list will move the selected item slightly up each time the key.down fires.  Is there a way to make this scale proof ? It also happens when using page zoom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is what happens:

> In case of transforms, the offsetWidth and offsetHeight returns the element's layout width and height, while getBoundingClientRect() returns the rendering width and height.

[MDN: Determining the dimensions of elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CSS_Object_Model/Determining_the_dimensions_of_elements#How_much_room_does_it_use_up.3F)

So, in this case clientHeight has the same result as offsetHeight. You neeed to use getBoundingClientRect().

```
setScrollPosition () {
        if(+this.keyIndex >= 6){
          this.$refs.testMainDiv.scrollTop = (+this.keyIndex - 6) * this.$refs.testItemDiv[+this.keyIndex].getBoundingClientRect().height;
        }
        else{
          this.$refs.testMainDiv.scrollTop = 0;
        }
      }
```

I tested it with the browser scaling and it works, you try it with your display scaling and let's see.